# Recursive division for a maze

Tags: java, recursion, maze

I understand the basic principles of the idea behind traversing a maze. I have looked at numerous websites on how to go about making my maze recursive.

```
private static void makeMazeRecursive(char[][]level, int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
{

}
```

This is what I have to work with. How do I go about dividing the walls I was given (height = 25, width = 80)? Any help is very appreciated. 
Basically, I am given the blank slate of the maze, now my job is to make a recursive method for it.

Comment: Recursive on what? There is not enough information here as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are talking about traversing a maze recursively.

You can't solve this by recursing on the maze layout.  If you wanted to use recursion, you would need to do it on the path you are taking through the maze.  Conceptually:

- each step "forward" maps onto a recursive call, and
- each step that backtracks is a return from a recursive call.

But you also need to keep track of maze locations that you have previously encountered, or else your maze runner could get stuck in an infinite (recursive) loop.

---

If you are talking about *creating* a maze recursively, then I suspect the same approach would work ... except that the "have I been here before" logic is about preventing the creation of cycles in the maze, rather than stopping you going around in circles.  A mental model is that you want to "dig" the maze tunnels without "breaking through" into existing tunnels.